# Data Exchange Framework - need to install package on content delivery severs?

Tags: data-exchange-framework

The DEF installation guide says that

> In most cases, data synchronization will not run on Sitecore delivery
>   servers. The data that is synchronized, however, is used on those
>   servers. As a result, all parts of Data Exchange Framework must be
>   installed on Sitecore delivery servers.

Why is it necessary to install the CD DEF module on the CD servers as the data that is used there will be in the form of published Sitecore items, and won't be connected to DEF at that stage. What am I missing?

This is a question for us as there are different DEF CD and CM packages but we only have one source of Sitecore items in source control for both CM and CD. Im wondering why they need to be installed on CD servers at all..

Comment: It all depends on what you are doing I guess with DEF. If there is nothing that needs updating in CD (some kind of real time feed for instance) then I don't see why you would need it installed there. Even so you can set a task to publish from CM. Most of the feeds I have done updated CM, but they were run either daily or every few hours.

Comment: Yes, We are just publishing periodicaly or will be once I get it working so seems nothing to deploy on CD. Will test and provide an answer here unless you want to.. Are you publishing by a pipeline step? I have another question about getting that to be called https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11799/data-exchange-framework-pipeline-step-never-called

Comment: If you think my response is an accepted an answer I think you can change it. :) As far as your other question. I am running into the same exact issue. I have been talking to Sitecore support about it.

Answer (score 2):

I double-checked and like confirmed my previous comment. It all depends on what you are doing with DEF. If there is nothing that needs updating in CD (some kind of real time feed for instance) then I don't see why you would need it installed there. Even so you can set a task to publish from CM. Most of the feeds I have done updated CM, but they were run either daily or every few hours.